# What does address 224.0.0.251:5353 represent?

Tags: netstat, ss

I read some tutorials,they say that netstat is deprecated. I tried `ss` command. THis is the output

```
Netid           State            Recv-Q            Send-Q                       Local Address:Port                        Peer Address:Port           Process           
icmp6           UNCONN           0                 0                                        *:58                                     *:*                                
udp             UNCONN           0                 0                              224.0.0.251:5353                             0.0.0.0:*                                
udp             UNCONN           0                 0                              224.0.0.251:5353                             0.0.0.0:*                                
udp             UNCONN           0                 0                              224.0.0.251:5353                             0.0.0.0:*                                
udp             UNCONN           0                 0                              224.0.0.251:5353                             0.0.0.0:*                                
udp             UNCONN           0                 0                                  0.0.0.0:5353                             0.0.0.0:*                                
udp             UNCONN           0                 0                                  0.0.0.0:40886                            0.0.0.0:*                                
udp             UNCONN           0                 0                            127.0.0.53%lo:53                               0.0.0.0:*                                
udp             UNCONN           0                 0                                  0.0.0.0:631                              0.0.0.0:*                                
udp             UNCONN           0                 0                                  0.0.0.0:17500                            0.0.0.0:*                                
udp             UNCONN           0                 0                                     [::]:5353                                [::]:*                                
udp             UNCONN           0                 0                                     [::]:55606                               [::]:*                                
udp             UNCONN           0                 0                                        *:41016                                  *:*                                
udp             UNCONN           0                 0                                        *:1716                                   *:*
```

ss -at at port 5353 shows

```
ss -aut '( dport = :5353 or sport = :5353 )'
Netid           State             Recv-Q            Send-Q                       Local Address:Port                       Peer Address:Port           Process           
udp             UNCONN            0                 0                              224.0.0.251:mdns                            0.0.0.0:*                                
udp             UNCONN            0                 0                              224.0.0.251:mdns                            0.0.0.0:*                                
udp             UNCONN            0                 0                              224.0.0.251:mdns                            0.0.0.0:*                                
udp             UNCONN            0                 0                              224.0.0.251:mdns                            0.0.0.0:*                                
udp             UNCONN            0                 0                              224.0.0.251:mdns                            0.0.0.0:*                                
udp             UNCONN            0                 0                                  0.0.0.0:mdns                            0.0.0.0:*                                
udp             UNCONN            0                 0                                     [::]:mdns                               [::]:*
```

Can someone explain how to interpret it?

Comment: You're looking at UDP ports in the `netstat` output, but you don't include `-u` in the `ss` command (but `-t` for TCP ports, so I assume you know what you're doing).  Is that intentional? Port 5353 is generally a MDNS responder, having to do with host name lookups (see `grep '^mdns' /etc/services`).

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks.I have not seen it before. Who created it? I have not added any printers nor installed anything new to Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Check `sudo lsof -i :mdns`. You'll see an `avahi-daemon` process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

224.0.0.251 is [Multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS), and it use the port 5353 (as you noticed). Many operating systems use it to discover new devices/printers/routers with zero or nearly zero configuration. E.g. if you want to send a page to be print to your printer, with e.g. the address *my-printer.local*, your operating system uses such port to look for the device which is named *my-printer*